# gnuplot : plot function using palette/gradient linecolor : seems uniform, not gradient

Tags: function, plot, gnuplot, gradient, palette

What does `gnuplot` need to plot the line of a function** using the `palette` linecolor i.e. as a gradient? (I tried `terminal wxt 0 enhanced` and `svg`, but will try more)? The documentation says `palette` is "used to color pm3d surfaces, heat maps, and other plot elements."

**POST-ANSWER NOTE No. 1: the function type will matter significantly - e.g. `set parametric` is quite different from, e.g, `sin(x)` - vide infra.

A [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723358/color-gradient-on-datapoints-based-on-rows-in-gnuplot) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569110/gnuplot-logarithmic-color-box-with-plot-palette) Stack Overflow posts show how to use gnuplot to plot *data* points from an input data file as a gradient, using `palette` as the `linecolor` - these work as described in my hands and in the `wxt` and `svg` terminals (not shown - I will try some other ones).

I tried plotting `sin(x)` as described :

```
reset
unset key
set palette defined ( 0 "blue", 1 "red" )
plot sin(x) lw 3 lc palette z
```

I can see the gradient bar/key on the right, going from -10 to 10 (red), but the line appears to be at zero on the scale (in this case) - neither -10 (blue) or 10 (red) (see image):

[image: blue-to-red palette gradient with sin function]

as an aside : I thought `set key off` should keep the key from appearing on the plot? seems not (this apparently uses the default `palette`): (spoiler: to turn off the color scale/key bar on the right: `unset colorbox` - see comment that follows answer below.)

```
reset
set key off
plot sin(x) lw 3 lc palette z
```

[image: default palette - key off not working I guess]

An example of what I am looking for - a function plotted using a line that continuously changes color as displayed on the graph - is found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174917/2-d-line-gradient-color-in-matlab) SO post about `matlab`.

To conclude : is something missing from the `gnuplot` commands above to get a function like `sin(x)` plotted with a gradient - or perhaps recurring gradient, so it starts over again?

programs/environment used:

gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 2

Ubuntu 22.04

POST-ANSWER NOTE No. 2: It is important to take care with the plot commands. If `w l` is omitted, as in this script:

```
### plot with lines with palette
### directly from the answer except omitting w l
reset session
unset key
set palette defined ( 0 "blue", 1 "red" )

# plot command to show plus signs:
plot '+' u 1:(sin(x)):(sin(x)) lc palette z
#
# original answer plot commands:
#plot '+' u 1:(sin(x)):(sin(x)) w l lw 3 lc palette z
### end of script
```

... literal plus signs `+` will be plotted :
[image: demonstration of plus signs being plotted.]

Just worth being aware of it, is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `palette z` for variable line color you have to give a z-column, e.g. `plot ... (x):(y):(z)...`. This doesn't work directly if you are using functions.

But you have the special filename `+` (check `help special-filenames`) which is similar but where you can give columns, e.g.

```
plot '+' u 1:(sin($1)):(sin($1)) w lines palette z
```

Instead of `$1` you could also use `x`.

**Script:**

```
### plot with lines with palette
reset session
unset key
set palette defined ( 0 "blue", 1 "red" )

plot '+' u 1:(sin(x)):(sin(x)) w l lw 3 lc palette z
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Amazing! I'd really like to use this in parametric equations, should it work? I tried taking the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828702/gnuplot-parametric-equation-positive-variable-ok-negative-variable-confusing) post - and in particular, I made the change at line 15: ```plot '+' u x(t),y(t) w l lw 2  lc palette z ``` but get ```undefined variable: t```.

Comment: @Bryan-StackExchange well, you can check `help parametric`, but I guess you have the same issue: where is your "z-column"? You can do everything with `'+'`, e.g. `plot [0:1] '+' u (x($1)):(y($1)):(z($1)) w l lc palette z`.

Comment: I see - I have a dilemma - post another question on that specific case - parametric equations colored with ```palette``` - or add a short _post_-_facto_ note to this question - because it seems important, what kind of equation - parametric, etc. Perhaps I could do both. Answer is good, I think, either way.

Comment: and can the key/scale be turned off.

Comment: @Bryan-StackExchange `unset colorbox`. Check `help colorbox`.

Comment: this might be for a whole other question on special filenames in gnuplot : how to adjust the pointsize of the ```+```? I didn't even realize it is literally a ```+``` being plotted, so I started looking into terminal types, the characters available, and trying e.g. ```pt 2``` in the plot command - and it seems that the ```'+'```, ```'++```unadjustable - so tricks like ```'.'```, ```{\267}```, or ```'\.'```` are not going to work. .. a practical problem was gnuplot generating an enormous plot file size because of the number of ```+```.

Comment: @Bryan-StackExchange yes, that's a completely different question. The special-filename `'+'` has nothing to do with the pointtype (`pt 1` is the symbol `+`). Check `help special-filenames`. About the size check `help pointsize` and `help with`.

Comment: I understand, yet it is interesting that a literal ```+``` is literally plotted on the output graph - at least in certain cases. I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @Bryan-StackExchange type `test` in the gnuplot console and you will see the different pointtype symbols. If you want to plot, e.g. the character `A` as point use `plot .... w p pt "A"`. Check `help points`.

Comment: a brief note: after the ```plot``` command, ```w l lw 3``` indeed produces nice lines. however, one might try, for instance, ```lw 3``` - this will produce a series of literal plus signs - e.g. ```+```, following the function. so for the script above, use ```plot '+' u 1:(sin(x)):(sin(x)) lw 3 lc palette z``` to see this. Perhaps this is bad form or not - but worth knowing and seeing.